# Multiplot of multiplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently discovered the `multiplot` function from the `Rmisc` package to produce stacked plots using `ggplot2` plots/objects. What I am trying to do now is to create a multiplot of multiplots. Unfortunately, unlike the `ggplot` function, `multiplot` does not produce objects, so my issue cannot be resolved by simply nesting `multiplot`.

I will create a dataframe to make my point clear. In my dataframe named `df`, I have 3 columns: `period`, `group` and `value`. A certain value is recorded for each of 3 groups over 10 periods. (Note: I don't use a seed number below despite the use of the `sample` function because the focus is not numerical, it is graphical)

```
# Create a data frame for illustration purposes
df <- data.frame(period = rep(1:10, 3),
                 group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 10),
                 value = sample(100, 30, replace = TRUE))
```

I then add a fourth column to `df`, which is the exponential transformation of the `value` column.

```
df$exp.value = exp(df$value)
```

I would like to create stacked plots allowing me to compare the values in each group to their exponential counterparts.

```
 # Split dataframe by group
 df_split <- split(df, df$group)

 # Plots of values in each group
 plots <- lapply(df_split, function(i){
   ggplot(data = i, aes(x = period, y = value)) + geom_line()
})

 # Plots of logged values in each group
 plots_exp <- lapply(df_split, function(i){
   ggplot(data = i, aes(x = period, y = exp.value)) + geom_line()
})
```

`plots` and `plots_exp` are both lists of 3 elements each containing `ggplot` objects. The first element of each list corresponds to group A, the second element corresponds to group B and the third element corresponds to group C.

In order to compare each group's values to the exponential values, I can use the `multiplot` function. Following is an example with group A:

```
multiplot(plots[[1]], plots_log[[1]], cols = 1)
```

[image: value_exp.value_grpA]

How can I create a grid which will include the multiplot above as well as the ones for groups B and C? As if the code included `... + facet_grid(. ~ group)`?

Comment: Why not plot 3 rows and 2 columns, 6 plots? Also, see [cowplot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) for multiplots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use *cowplot* package:

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(plots[[1]], plots_exp[[1]],
          plots[[2]], plots_exp[[2]],
          plots[[3]], plots_exp[[3]],
          labels = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
          ncol = 1, align = "v")
```

[image]

We can output to a pdf looping through *plots* and *plots_exp* list objects. Every page will contain 2 plots. This is a better option when we have a lot of groups:

```
pdf("myPlots.pdf")
lapply(seq(length(plots)), function(i){
  plot_grid(plots[[i]], plots_exp[[i]], ncol = 1, align = "v")
})
dev.off()
```

Another option is to prepare the data for *ggplot* and use *facet* as usual:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

gather(df, valueType, value, -c(group, period)) %>% 
  mutate(myGroup = paste(group, valueType)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(period, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(myGroup ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]